# Не запускается приложение, созданное приложением на C#

Tags: c#

```
string base64Encoded = "base64";
string base64Decoded;
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
base64Decoded = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\..\\..\\App\\App.exe", base64Decoded);
```

Выдаёт ошибку при запуске созданного приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы рассчитываете, что строка `"base64"` превратится в содержимое выполняемого файла?

Comment: @Igor там слишком много символов, но если раскодировать на сайте, то приложение будет работать.

Comment: Вам надо сохранять в файл массив `data`, а не строку.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо сохранять в файл массив `data`, а не строку.